# list.reverse() in Python

Tags: python, methods

I am new to python and have started to learn lesson on Lists. I am trying to reverse the order of a list using list.reverse() method.

```
new_list = ['a','e','x','b','c']

print new_list

new_list = new_list.reverse()

print new_list
```

When I run these command, I see the output as below:

```
['a', 'e', 'x', 'b', 'c']
```

None

**Question:**

Since I am reassigning new_list with reversed order of the previously assigned new_list, why am I seeing the Output of second print statement as None?

Thank you very much in advance..!

Comment: The `reverse` method reverses a list "in place" and returns no useful value.